# How to get complete content for a single post that was splitted into pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress post which was divided into multiple pages using pager break `<!--nextpage-->` tag and it's pagination functionality is working as expected for single post page.

```
www.example.com/url-post-content/1
www.example.com/url-post-content/2
www.example.com/url-post-content/3
```

But problem is my category page where i am showing all posts for a category with pagination(single post on each page).

I want to show complete content of the post(without pagination) on my category post page because here i am showing single post per page for the category but `the_content` function in my loop returning content of only first page for a post which was divided into pages using `<!--nextpage-->` tag.

Need you help to find out a way for displaying complete content of a post which was splitted in pages using page break tag.

Comment: unclear question what you're trying to  ask give some more details to help.

Comment: If a wordpress post is splitted into multiple pages using <!--nextpage--> tag, It dont show the whole content of the post. How can i see all content of that particular post?

Comment: [Will you contact me in chat please?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8321664/muhammad-nouman)

Answer (score 0):

You can get complete content of post using code below.

Retrieves post data using [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) function.

```
$post_object = get_post($post_id); //     
/// Now, you have post object and can get complete post content from post object
$post_content = $post_object->post_content;
```

use [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) or [apply_filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) to properly format your post content.

```
echo do_shortcode($post_content);
```